# Passing a list of <string>,<object> parameters to a method C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following parameter being passed. Notice the second parameters contains int and string (*it does not always have to be `Area` and `CustomerName`, it can be any names*):

```
UpdateCustomer(customerId, new { Area = 23, CustomerName = "Bob Smith" });
```

Here is the function

```
public void UpdateCustomer(int customerId,
                           dynamic parameters)  // Is is correct to define it as "dynamic" or should it be something else?
```

My question is how would I do a foreach on the parameters and extract both the name/value of each parameter?

I get an error on the `foreach` line:

```
// Setup Parameters
foreach (var v in (parameters as dynamic))
{
    if (v is KeyValuePair<string, string>)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else if (v is KeyValuePair<string, int>)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will it *always* be an area and a name? Is there a reason you want to use an anonymous type and dynamic typing instead of creating a class to combine those two?

Comment: The usual approach when (ab)using anonymous types like this is to pass them as `object` (`dynamic` adds nothing here) and then reflect over them with `.GetProperties()`. This is not something you should find yourself doing frequently, consider declaring non-anonymous types instead (`record`s are particularly convenient).

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for your response.   I updated the question.  It does not always have to be Area and CustomerName, it can be any names.

Comment: How did you manage to paint yourself into this particular corner?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method name maybe passing an action to update a customer is a suitable option for you? Something like this:

```
public void UpdateCustomer(int id, Action<Customer> action)
{
    Customer customer = ...// get customer
    action(customer);
}
```

And usage which will be a little bit more wordy but still:

```
UpdateCustomer(1, customer =>
{
    customer.Area = 23;
    customer.CustomerName = "Bob Smith";
});
```

Comment: Hi Guru thank you for your answer.  This would not work since the parameters names can change.   They are not hard-coded to "Area" and "CustomerName".

Comment: @RobertSmith can you please add some more explanation what you are actually doing inside the method?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the parameters as an `object` (there is no need to pass it as a `dynamic`) and iterate over its properties using Reflection. From there you can get the name, value, and type, and use them, for example, to create a parameters collection for a database call, as in this example:

```
public DataTable RunQuery(string connectionString, string storedProcedure, object parameters)
{
    var type = parameters.GetType();
    var properties = type
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(p => p.DeclaringType == type)
        .ToArray();
    var sqlParameters = properties
        .Select
        (
            p => new SqlParameter
            {
                SqlDbType = p.PropertyType.ToSqlDbType(),
                ParameterName = p.Name,
                Value = p.GetValue(parameters)
            }
        )
        .ToArray();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand { Connection = connection })
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var table = new DataTable();
                table.Load(reader);
                return table;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then pass an anonymous object as the parameters.

```
RunQuery(GetConnectionString(), "UpdateCustomer",  new { Area = 23, CustomerName = "Bob Smith" });
```

Comment: If it's specifically used to fire off a query on a database, I would suggest using Dapper rather than reinventing the wheel, because there are many niggling details to get right. Notably, your code will not compile as-is -- I would guess that `.ToSqlDbType` is a custom extension method. (And `DataTable` is a memory hog and should be avoided unless there really is a need for dynamic result sets; Dapper's deserialization logic also helps there.)